# images pagination - how to get all params in one single query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a pagination system for viewing images from database.
So each time I click on a `next / prev` buttons I need three variables
Question - is there a way to get them in one single query and not using a separate query for each of them?

```
$lm = 100; // limit per page  
$off = 0; // offset - click on next prev buttons  
$dim = '960 x 540'; // img dimensions  

function get_images($lm, $off, $dim){
global $db;
//firstly I need total number of images 
$st = $db->query("select count(*) as cnt from images");
$total = $st->fetchColumn(); 

//then I need number of 960 x 540 images  
$st = $db->query("select * from images where dim = '" . $dim . "'");
$insel = $st->rowCount();  

//then I need number of viewed images on a pagination system        
$st = $db->query("select * from images where dim = '" . $dim . "' order by date desc limit " . $lm . " 
offset " . $off);
$inview = $st->rowCount();
```

Comment: Your queries are wide open for SQL injection, and also I don't really see any way to combine them.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sql injection using a `select` query - have you any example pls. There is no any `insert` or `update` or `alter` query here

Comment: I think if `$dim` = `" image.something = something  OR '1 = 1 " `
will return all images. 
Correct me if i'm wrong this is sql injection.

Comment: @TrầnXuânHuy maybe but there is no any danger of such an `injection`. If someone want to hack a server just in order to view more images on its comp - I would ignore that.

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about all the non-sql stuff for now, and instead see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

```
$st = $db->query("select * from images where dim = '" . $dim . "' count(id) over(partition by id) as cnt  count(dim) over(partition by dim) as insel order by date desc limit " . $lm . " offset " . $off);
```

But make sure you are using MySQL version greater than or equal to 8.0

Comment: could you please explain your answer and highlight the code. It is very difficult to make out the actual code in your answer.